# using localstorage in hmtl5 to store a dynamically created div without using database

Tags: android, html, cordova, mobile, local-storage

I am trying to develop a web app (hybrid application) using Html5 css3 jquery, jquery mobile phonegap and Dreamweaver cs6.

in my application I have three select box with different options and a button. When user clicks on the button after selecting options of all three select box a div will be created. till here its fine, but once the app is refreshed or moved to another page and come I am loosing the div created. this app is a demo app so I am not using any database. is there a way I can store using local storage  to save this div so that i can retrieve when I come back to app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can

Save it

```
if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        var divtosave = $("#divtosave").html();
        localStorage.setItem('saveddiv', divtosave);
});
```

Use it

```
if ('saveddiv' in localStorage) {
        $("#div").html(localStorage.getItem('saveddiv'));
}
```

Clear it

```
localStorage.clear(); //release it
```